# Magento reset one module database

Tags: database, magento, magento-1.6

I messed up with a module, how can I reset it's tables (not empty, but reset) like it is fresh installed? I don't wont to reinstall the module, I just want to reset the data in database.

Magento Version: 1.6.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To reset a module data, you have to delete it's resource related entry, this way magento will rerun setup script again.

Example:
Let's say you want to reset the newsletter module data.

If you check

```
app/core/Mage/Newsletter/etc/config.etc
```

You can find

```
<resources>
    <newsletter_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Mage_Newsletter</module>
        </setup>
    </newsletter_setup>
</resources>
```

This means the resource name is **newsletter_setup**

Log in to your database, find the table **core_resource**, find the entry where the 
code = **newsletter_setup** delete it.

Now if you refresh the page, Magento will run the setup script again, in this case, it is

```
app/core/Mage/Newsletter/etc/sql/install-1.6.0.0.php
```